# Move a file from directory to another using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a file on one application folder of codiginitor and I want to copy that file to another application folder of codignitor in another directory.
I have tried below code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$file = 'http://xxxxxx/jakson_solar/ftp.php';
$newfile = './mobile_image/transfer/';

if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
    echo "Copy success!"; die;
}else{
    echo "Copy failed."; die;
}
```

is there another way to copy file from one directory to another directory?

Comment: Your first argument is not a directory, it's a file on a - possibly - different webserver. Ergo, the filesystems may even differ. You could use file_get_contents to pull a file from another location and then write/create a new file on your server. Check php manual for more information on how to use file_get_contents. If you want the php source you may have to get access to the FTP and use fopen or something. We would then maybe require more information.

Comment: "doesn't seem to be work" is not a sufficient description of your issue. What does your http servers error log file tell you what the actual issue is?

Comment: @dev: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) requires as first parameter an input *file* and as second parameter an output *file*

So do it this way

```
$file = 'path_to/ftp.php';
$newfile = './mobile_image/transfer/ftp.php';

if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
    echo "Copy success!"; die;
} else {
    echo "Copy failed."; die;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**@dev please find the code below for your needs**

```
// 1 check if your input from the form is not empty
if ((isset($_FILES['file']))){

    // 2. files inside the session
    $_SESSION['FILES'] = $_FILES;

    // 3. your path
    $PATH = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mobile_image/transfer/";

    // 4. temporary name -> optional step but recommended
    $TEMP_NAME = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]);

    // 5. new name of the file
    $NAME_NEW = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,20) . '.' .end($TEMP_NAME);
    $UPLOAD_FILE = $PATH . basename($NAME_NEW);

    // 6. check before moving the file that is not empty
    if (isset($UPLOAD_FILE)) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'], $PATH);   }

    // 7. custom errors
    $json = array();
    $json['status'] = "OK";
    $json['message'] = 'File moved successfully';
    echo json_encode($json);

}else{
    // 7. custom errors
    $json = array();
    $json['status'] = "NO FILE";
    $json['message'] = 'No files found';
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Where in the given code does a form occur? The OP has not posted anything about uploaded files

Comment: @NicoHaase is asking for moving the files, is not said with form or without, hope he can find the code, because as well can be used for moving files without form

Comment: Using `move_uploaded_file`, you can only move uploaded files. If that file is not given in the current `POST` request, it won't do anything